# How to compare two list using Scala?

Tags: scala

I have two lists

```
val firstList = List(("A","B",12),("P","Q",13),("L","M",21))
val secondList = List(("A",11),("P",34),("L",43))
```

I want output as below

```
val outPutList = List(("P","Q",13,34),("L","M",21,43))
```

I want to compare third member of firstList to second element of secondList. This means - 
I want to check second list value as `secondList.map(_.2)` is greater than first list as `firstList.map(_.3)`

Answer (score 7):

Using a for comprehension as follows,

```
for ( ((a,b,m), (c,n)) <- (firstList zip secondList) if n > m) yield (a,b,m,n)
```